# How do I check if a database is running in read only mode?

Tags: java, oracle

How do I check if an oracle database is running in read only mode?

I was looking at the below api method, but this returns false irrespective of the database in read only mode.
The source code for this method, does nothing but returns false.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDatabaseMetaData.html#isReadOnly__

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why do you believe that the database is in read-only mode when the JDBC driver tells you it is not?  It is possible to start a database in read-only mode but that is very, very uncommon.

Comment: Do you control the database? One obvious but brute force method would be to attempt to update a row in a table and see if it succeeds. You could have a table set aside for just this purpose, with one row, which doesn't otherwise contain any meaningful data.

Comment: @Gilbert, David - Thanks, I thought of that, but I wanted to have that as last option, will keep that in mind anyways.

Comment: @JustinCave The original issue was, we have 2 databases to support failover with JBOSS as APP server. For some reason at few instances without even the primary database going down, jboss switches to the secondary database, while the secondary is still in read only mode, which is causing the application fail.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
select open_mode from v$database;
```

Comment: thank you, that was a nice and simple way, but the database user that we are using, does not have the privileges to query this table. Which is why am trying to make use of any API if any.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Java guy, so, I can't help you with Java API option.  As someone else suggested, you could attempt DML and then check for ORA-016000 error.  If you get ORA-016000 on DML attempt, database is read only.